# LD_PRELOAD'd jemalloc causes GLIB_2.32 not found

Tags: glibc, rhel, libc, jemalloc

## Problem

I'm trying to profile a Java program which uses JNI. I'm using [this](https://poonamparhar.github.io/troubleshooting_native_memory_leaks/) as a guide.

I've downloaded [version 5.3.0 of jemalloc](https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/releases/tag/5.3.0).

I've done `configure` and `make` to build it (in the rockylinux:8.8 container).

I copy that directory to a RHEL8 system.

I run `java` with the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable equal to the path to `libjemalloc.so.2`.

I get:

```
/lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32` not found (required by /some-path/libjemalloc.so.2)
```

## What I've done

I'm assuming that jemalloc has released something which is compatible with the version of libc that I am running (which is 2.28 on RH8). It seems like jemalloc should have a compatibility matrix with glibc, but I can't find it anywhere, and looking through the source I don't see any references to a `2.32`.

How can I get my java program to run with `jemalloc`?

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with jemalloc. What you see is that your build system has newer glibc than the system you run it on (and consequently, binaries built there can't run on older libc).

Comment: `version GLIB_2.32 not found` is _not_ a message that was actually produced. Please show what _actually_ happened.